Django doesnt update the translation
I am trying to add Translation to russian from english
I tried clearing the cache, deleting locale folder, changing the translation. it all doesnt work
#: core/templates/core/layout.html:59 core/templates/core/layout.html:112
msgid "Home"
msgstr "Главная"

But it displays "Начало" instead of "Главная".
my settings.py:
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ("en", ('English')),
    ("ru", ('Russian')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/'),
)


did you run "manage.py compilemessages" command?

Yes, i ran this command
